# questions about linux DOS and BIOS on new laptop

Tags: linux, laptop, bios

I want to buy a new laptop, which has no windows on it; it uses Linux. It's a Lenovo G400

I never used Linux before so please bear with me. My question is, can i access the BIOS from Linux so I can install windows like usual?

Thanks for your help :D

Comment: There is no such thing like Linux DOS (It's actually 2 separate operating systems as Windows are). Yes, you can install Windows (if you have a license for that :)) as usual instead of linux or whatever. You need BIOS only to change boot device priority, to prioritize your DVD-Rom, USB Thumb drive or whatever

Comment: Provided the laptop firmware doesn't prevent the installation of Windows you should be able to install Windows.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for your help. How to check the firmware prevented it or not? I want to buy lenovo g400 :D

Comment: Also the laptop needs to fullfill the requirements of windows. There are some (mostly Android) Notebooks that don't have a CPU supported by windows.

Comment: @BlazeTama - Do your research.  `Lenovo` does not sell locked firmware products.

Comment: @Ramhound sorry i do searched and i found out they have no windows, thats why im asking here. So do you mean its possible to install windows and delete the linux?

Comment: @BlazeTama - I already address your question.  Combine my two statements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your best bet is to get in front of the laptop and see what you can do.

What you are looking for is the capability of booting from a CD - whether inbuilt or via USB.  A secondary option is to be able to boot from a USB flashdrive, which you can also use to install Windows.

If these options exist (they are normally accessed via a key press at boot time) then the operating system currently on the hard disk does not matter.  You can overwrite it and install whatever you like.  Including sticking with Linux :)

The chances are very low that you will not being able to boot the laptop from some sort of removable media that you can use to install Windows.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, it has DVD and USB ports. However, im afraid the firmware is locking the OS (like the comments above). Will i be able to install windows on Lenovo G400? :D

Comment: @BlazeTama You should be able to install any Operating System (OS) of your choice, whether its Linux, or Windows. The system (laptop) may not come with any OS, but it just means you are free to install whatever you want on it. Note: Some OS may have minimum hardware requirement, so as long as your laptop is better than those minimum hardware requirement, you are good to go.

Comment: @BlazeTama Simply ask the vendor. It isn't likely, but if you have these concerns, ask and get an answer, in writing if you need it.  If it turns out to be false, you get your money back.

Comment: This looks to be an older laptop that is before the days of locking, which would only affect Windows 8 anyway and only if it had been bought with the OS associated to the hardware.